# Выравнять Список (<li><label><input> отступы input по отношению к label) css

Tags: css

Как можно выравнять input-ы, чтобы они были на одном уровне и не зависили от длинны текста label

```css
.div-detail-general {
  width: 50em;
  margin: 10px;
  border-left-width: 5px;
  border-left-color: #7ac943;
  border-left-style: solid;
}

.div-detail-general h3 {
  margin: 0 0 0 8px;
}

.list-content-page-detail {
  list-style: none;
}

.list-content-page-detail label {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin: 0 0 0 18px;
}

.list-content-page-detail li {}

.label-search-list {}

.input-list-detail {
  border-color: #8d9ab1;
  width: 32em;
  height: 2em;
  margin: 8px 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-detail-general">
  <h3>Заголовок</h3>
  <ul class="list-content-page-detail">
    <li>
      <label for="text1">Текст ок</label>
      <input type="text" class="input-list-detail" name="text1" id="text1">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="text2">Текст</label>
      <input type="search" class="input-list-detail label-search-list" name="text2" id="text2">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="text3">Текстик</label>
      <input type="search" class="input-list-detail" name="text3" id="text3">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="text4">Текст длинный</label>
      <input type="datetime-local" class="input-list-detail" name="text4" id="text4">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно обернуть `label` в `div` и добавить ему `min-width`по самому длинному тексту

```css
.div-detail-general {
  width: 50em;
  margin: 10px;
  border-left-width: 5px;
  border-left-color: #7ac943;
  border-left-style: solid;
}

.div-detail-general h3 {
  margin: 0 0 0 8px;
}

.list-content-page-detail {
  list-style: none;
}

.list-content-page-detail li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.list-content-page-detail li div {
  min-width: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.list-content-page-detail div label {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin: 0 0 0 18px;
}


.input-list-detail {
  border-color: #8d9ab1;
  width: 32em;
  height: 2em;
  margin: 8px 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-detail-general">
  <h3>Заголовок</h3>
  <ul class="list-content-page-detail">
    <li>
      <div>
        <label for="text1">Текст ок</label>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="input-list-detail" name="text1" id="text1">
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <label for="text2">Текст</label>
      </div>
      <input type="search" class="input-list-detail label-search-list" name="text2" id="text2">
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <label for="text3">Текстик</label>
      </div>
      <input type="search" class="input-list-detail" name="text3" id="text3">
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <label for="text4">Текст длинный</label>
      </div>
      <input type="datetime-local" class="input-list-detail" name="text4" id="text4">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```