# Хочу улучшить CSS код

Tags: html, css

Есть у меня форма

[image: картинка 1]

И я хочу чтобы инпуты были в одну линию
И я это делаю так

```
#name{
    margin-left: 49px;
}

#Adr{
    margin-left: 70px;
}

#N_m{
    margin-left: 68px;
}

#id{
    margin-left: 70px;
}

#Full_name{
    margin-left: 4px;
}

#Phone{
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Получается, то что я хочу. Но этот метод мне кажется топорным и глупым, может кто подскажет вариант лучше.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сделай полный пример с html...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1209045/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%a1%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-lilabelinput-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf%d1%8b-input-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%ba-label-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант на Flex без строгой привязки к размерам элементов

```css
.line {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

label, input {
  flex: 1 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class='line'>
  <label>123</label>
  <input />
</div>
<div class='line'>
  <label>1234567890</label>
  <input />
</div>
<div class='line'>
  <label>12345</label>
  <input />
</div>
</div>
```

И еще один вариант, чтобы расположить элементы на всю ширину род. контейнера

```css
.line {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 10px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class='line'>
  <label>123</label>
  <input />
</div>
<div class='line'>
  <label>1234567890</label>
  <input />
</div>
<div class='line'>
  <label>12345</label>
  <input />
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ты полностью уверен в нужности такого форматирования форм? :)

Answer (score 2):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 5px;
}

.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent">
    <span>Name</span>
    <input/>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <span>Name name</span>
    <input/>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <span>Name name Name name</span>
    <input/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> я хочу чтобы инпуты были в одну линию

Поскольку ТС не привел пример своей разметки - предложу такой вариант верстки для полей...

```css
.line {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.line label {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class='line'>
  <label>123</label>
  <input />
</div>
<div class='line'>
  <label>1234567890</label>
  <input />
</div>
<div class='line'>
  <label>12345</label>
  <input />
</div>
```

Comment: Но зачем привязка к конкретному width label? Это же плохой вариант получается, не сильно лучше изначального варианта ТС

Comment: @Gelloiss, тут привели несколько других вариантов - используй их.

Comment: Та я свой вариант написал) Просто реально зачем эта строгая привязка к размеру? по-моему, это плохой подход

Comment: @Gelloiss, я не могу ответить на твой вопрос, т.к. изначально проблема вообще не моя. Пусть ТС выбирает любой вариант решения.

Answer (score 1):

Также подключусь со своим решением **без** flex'ов и вообще хоть какого-нибудь **css**.

Выровнять можно обычным `table`:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="name">name:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="name" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="email">email:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="email" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="password">password:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="password" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Можно. Но зачем? Чем вам css не угодил?))

Comment: @Gelloiss если вам обязательно нужен **css** - велком использовать другие варианты, представленные здесь)) Просто как альтернатива, почему нет?))